# Go Random number always return 168

Tags: go

I am a complete noob in regards to Go.

I am trying to make a an arbitrary function that returns two random numbers added together.

I have pasted my code below, and cannot figure out why it always returns 168!

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func add(x int, y int) int{
    return x + y
}

var a int = rand.Intn(100)
var b int = rand.Intn(100)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(add(a, b))
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? 168 seems like a pretty random number to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to specify seed to get different numbers. It is outlined in [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/):

> Top-level functions, such as Float64 and Int, use a default shared
>   Source that produces a deterministic sequence of values each time a
>   program is run. Use the Seed function to initialize the default Source
>   if different behavior is required for each run.

And some reference about [Seed](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed)

> Seed uses the provided seed value to initialize the default Source to
>   a deterministic state. If Seed is not called, the generator behaves as
>   if seeded by Seed(1).

And you can see an example in the go [cookbook](http://golangcookbook.blogspot.com/2012/11/generate-random-number-in-given-range.html):

`rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())`

So wrapping up, you will have something like this:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func add(x int, y int) int{
    return x + y
}


func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    var a int = rand.Intn(100)
    var b int = rand.Intn(100)
    fmt.Println(add(a, b))
}
```